Understanding Exact RG equation to Wavefunction Renormalization
In lecture notes on EFT and the Standard Model by David Simmons-Duffin, he introduces exact RG equation and explains that when we do RG running from UV energy scale to IR energy scale, there would be additional interaction terms in Lagrangian $L_{\Lambda}[\phi]$, given by in eq(2.62).
$$Λ\frac{∂L_Λ[ϕ]}{∂Λ}= −1/2(∂_ϕ^{T} G′_{Λ}∂_ϕ)L_{Λ}[ϕ] + 1/2(∂_ϕL_Λ[ϕ])^TG′_Λ(∂_ϕL_Λ[ϕ])\tag{2.62}$$
where $G_{\Lambda}' = \Lambda\partial G_{\Lambda}/\partial \Lambda$, and $G_{\Lambda}$ is Green function with cut-off function.
Then he introduces an scalar field example with $\phi^4$ and $\phi^6$ interaction,
and show that when running couplings from UV to IR around the free theory $L_{\Lambda}[\phi] = 0$, they would be attracted to a submanifold $M_{\Lambda}$.
And he claims that the submanifold would be parametrized by couplings of relevant and marginal operators.
My question, when he says in the above case, there are three relevant and marginal operators, which is $\phi^2$, $(\partial\phi)^2$, and $\phi^4$, I'm confused about the emergence of $\phi^2$ and $(\partial\phi)^2$. I know they are corresponding to mass renormalization and wave function renormalization, but Simmons-Duffin seems to take unusual approach (that is, Exact RG) to me.
How to see their emergence from exact RG equation?

In how may dimensions?

@Qmechanic It is 4.
